# Doubt regarding de Broglie relation from group velocity

Tags: waves, wave-particle-duality

This is a derivation of de Broglie relation from my textbook.[image]
I'm confused regarding the following:

In the equation $p=\hbar k + c$ the author sets $c=0 $  by stating $ p=0 $ so $k=0$. I don't understand how did he get this condition. One way to get this was setting the LHS of the first equation to zero. Then $\omega=constant$ or $f=constant$ and $v=0=\lambda f$ so you get $\lambda=0$ and thus $k=0$. Is this procedure correct? How can a wave packet have a well defined wavelength? I don't understand what $\lambda$ or $f$ mean in this context.

Comment: What would happen if $p\neq 0$ when $k=0$? What would it mean physically?

Comment: When $p=0$ the particle is at rest

Comment: However I haven't yet proved the relation between $p$ and $\lambsa$. That's my question!

Comment: You do work with a $k$ that is a wave number characterizing a wave. If $k\rightarrow 0$, $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ and the wave becomes a uniform, synchronous oscillation over the entire space. Could this sort of oscillation carry a directional momentum $p \neq 0$?

Comment: As far as I know a group of waves representing a particle has no specific wavelength. We can take an average wavelength and work with it. And I don't think that kind of wave should carry momentum. But how do I propose such an argument before knowing that $p$ and $k$ are related? The constant $c$ could also contribute something. Which is the only step where I'm still confused.

Comment: So, if the wave(s) cannot carry momentum for $k\rightarrow 0$, $p=0$ necessarily and $c=0$. You don't need to know how $p$ and $k$ are related, just notice that at $k =0$ the wave must have translational symmetry in all directions. If $c$ weren't $0$ then $p\neq 0$ at $k=0$, which would mean uniform waves would carry nonzero momentum in some direction, although they behave the same in every direction. Just curious, the text you show already assumes $k$ in the group velocity eq. How is $k$ introduced in the first place?

Comment: See there is no one value of $k$ for a wavepacket right? It's multiple values centred around some fixed $k_0$. Sk does saying $k=0$ mean every wave's $k\rightarrow 0$ in the wave group ?

Comment: For a wave packet equation comprised of say two waves there are no k's or $\omega$'s. Just delta k and delta $\omega$ in the equation

Comment: I think I see where your confusion comes from. Yes, a wave packet is several/many or a whole continuum of superposed waves, but: the dependence $p(k)$ refers to $p$ for one wave, something the author forgets to mention. Otherwise $p$ for a wave packet involves an integral over the contributing waves, and one can't simply take the derivative $dp/dk$ from that. So instead of 2 waves in your last example just take 1 wave.

Comment: But one wave cannot represent a particle as it is not localised!